# How can I use marketing email templates with an API request?

Tags: rest, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to set up an API request for Dynamics 365 to send an email template to a specific user, and I am having a lot of difficulty getting it to do what I want.

I'm using the `SendEmailFromTemplate` action and so far only have access to global templates. Whenever I try to use a marketing email template, it says it's not found. Is it even possible for me to use Marketing email templates with this action?

Response

```
 "error": {
        "code": "0x80040217",
        "message": "template With Id = 41deb0fa-c108-eb11-a813-000d3a8c09cf Does Not Exist"
    }
```

Additionally, I've not been able to embed user data in the global templates such as `{{contact.address1_city}}`.

Current request:

```
{
  "TemplateId": "TEMPLATE-ID",
  "Regarding": {
    "contactid": "CONTACT-ID",
    "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.contact"
  },
  "Target": {
    "regardingobjectid_contact@odata.bind": "/contacts(CONTACT-ID)",
    "email_activity_parties": [{
      "partyid_systemuser@odata.bind": "/systemusers(SYSTEMUSER-ID)",
      "participationtypemask": 1
    }, {
      "partyid_contact@odata.bind": "/contacts(CONTACT-ID))",
      "participationtypemask": 2
    }],
    "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.email"
  }
}
```

I might be going about it the wrong way. Any assistance is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. Please provide your code here in your question. It's hard to troubleshoot in the dark.

Comment: Also, "I've not been able is not a problem description". Show the code, explain what it should do, and explain what it does instead, with verbatim quotes of any errors and full descriptions.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Just an API request at this point. No code to debug. I need to send a marketing email template with data from the users account. It works using a global template, but that not what I want to use.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not supported.

Marketing emails and CDS emails are two separate things - both business-wise and technically. Marketing emails are meant for sending emails in business to business and business to customer scenarios and are part of marketing solution. CDS emails are piece of core functionality.

If you do want to send marketing email your best shot is to use "quick send" instead.